cant inject spring bean into jsf managed Bean via @Inject @ManagedProperty("#{springBean}")
(using spring (spring-webmvc 6.1.13), jsf (jakartaee-web-api 9.1.0), maven, glassfish7)
i am trying to inject a spring bean into a jsf bean via @Inject @ManagedProperty("#{springBean}"). i was following the most upvoted answer from source1 but i couldnt get it to work, the server logs an error upon deployment:
[SEVERE] [] [jakarta.enterprise.web.vs.server] [tid: _ThreadID=71 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  WebModule[/demoNoBoot2-1.0]StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ZManagedBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'zService': No qualifying bean of type 'org.demoNoBoot2.zdemo.ZService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@jakarta.inject.Inject(), @jakarta.faces.annotation.ManagedProperty("#{zService}")}

spring service bean:
@Service
public class ZService {                                                                                                 // bean cannot be found by jsf DI

    @Autowired
    ZRepository zRepository;

    public void checkInjection() { System.out.println("service injection works"); }

    public void checkJpa() { System.out.println( zRepository.findById(1L).get().getUsername() + " jpa works");
  }
}


jsf managed Bean:
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ZManagedBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Inject @ManagedProperty("#{zService}")
    private ZService zService;

    private String password;
    private String username;


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;}

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;}

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;}

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;}


    public void register(String username, String password) {
        System.out.println(username + password + " jsf alone works");


        zService.checkInjection();

        zService.checkJpa();
    }

}

faces-config.xml & FacesConfiguration.java (followed source1)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
        xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
        https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>

@FacesConfig
@ApplicationScoped
public class FacesConfiguration {
}

both spring and jsf work on their own but i cant get them to work together (so i also left code out that wasnt relevant for the spring-jsf "connection")

Which package exactly did you import the @ManagedProperty annotation from? There are two but only one if them is correct for the combination with @Inject. The correct package is mentioned in the "source1" you found.

Thanks for reading my question! i am using:
import jakarta.faces.annotation.ManagedProperty;

Okay, next step is to check if you're not bitten by the discrepancy in Javabean naming conventions versus CDI naming conventions. As per Javabeans spec the default name of ZService would be ZService not zService because of the first two letters being capitals.

i did 2 things:
first i refactored the spring service to ZebraService (including @Inject @ManagedProperty(value="#{zebraService}") private ZebraService zebraService;) temporarily but got the same error log: [...] No qualifying bean of type 'org.demoNoBoot2.zdemo.ZebraService' available [...].
After reverting the temporary changes i made this change: @Inject @ManagedProperty(value="#{ZService}") private ZService zService;, but i got the same error log No qualifying bean of type 'org.demoNoBoot2.zdemo.ZService' available.
